# How to copy a folder, recursively, with progress feedback, while preserving all metadata on OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa, file-copying

I need to copy a folder from one location to another while providing my users with a **progress bar**.

The only appropiate API that I can find that **isn't** deprecated is copyfile(3). I've implemented this and the results are nearly perfect, however I've since discovered that neither the Finder comments nor the tags associated with original are copied over. Not only do I need them to be copied, but I'm worried about what other metadata isn't being copied that I'm not yet aware of.

Note that I am setting all the appropriate flags on copyfile to copy over the metadata.

How can I achieve my goal without resorting to awful techniques such as an Applescript bridge to read/write the comments using the Finder at the end of the copy?

## UPDATE

After much research I have discovered that both the comment and the tags *are* copied over in the file's extended attributes. However, the comment refuses to display in the Finder.

I saw it mentioned that the comment is *also* stored in the .DS_Store. As a test I deleted the .DS_Store file and then relaunched the Finder so that it would be regenerated. The comment still doesn't appear.

What needs to be done for the Finder to recognise this metadata?

Comment: NSWorkspace's duplicateURLs?

Comment: No, I need progress callbacks...

Comment: Have you checked if `-[NSFileManager copyItemAtURL:toURL:error:]` copies the comments and tags? If it does, you can build a method around it to copy entire directory hierarchies recursively. You use a directory enumerator to enumerate all of the files and copy them one at a time. You can present progress at file granularity. You don't copy the directories that are enumerated, you make a matching directory in the destination and then copy into it. You have to be careful to set its permissions (and other metadata) to match the original *after* copying into it, in case the source is non-writable.

Comment: The files I'm copying are large videos, I need a proper progress bar that updates continuously.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: this answer assumes you are correct about comments etc. not being copied, this has not been verified.*

`copyfile` is available in [source form from Apple](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/copyfile/copyfile-118.1.2/). You might need to tweak it a bit though to actually compile it. Once you've done that you can modify to add the features you wish.

HTH